# Ubuntu 16.04 server unable to detect intel graphics on I3 6100

Tags: 16.04, drivers, intel-graphics, intel

I have been trying to figure out why I can't get the integrated intel graphics to work on my new home server and believe I have found the problem but struggling to confirm or find a solution.

I purchased an I3 6100 cpu and have checked that is what arrived and I installed. The bios confirms this: https://photos.app.goo.gl/XVX988sFEPsIljIq2

However upon logging into the system itself I can see the I3 listed in /proc/cpuinfo but lspci and lshw are both referencing the xeon e3 1200/1500 neither of which have graphics so I am wondering if this is the problem and its not loading the drivers because of it. Details below:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
...
processor   : 3
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 94
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-6100 CPU @ 3.70GHz
stepping    : 3
microcode   : 0xa6
cpu MHz     : 899.996
cache size  : 3072 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 3
initial apicid  : 3
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 22
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb intel_pt tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 dtherm arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp
bugs        :
bogomips    : 7392.66
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 PCI bridge: ASPEED Technology, Inc. AST1150 PCI-to-PCI Bridge (rev 03)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family (rev 30)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
```

I have tried disabling the motherboards local graphics chip (the aspeed one) and this still didn't lead to the intel one becoming available or even detected (from what I could see).

Is their a trick I am missing, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It might be that the mainboard does not make use of the integrated Intel graphics. Best would be to contact Asus or the vendor of the mainboard/server.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see what I can find on that front